# Taggable system Error

Tags: php, tags, laravel-5

i am using this package

```
https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-taggable
```

Getting Error While i try to tag on my blog

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'taggable_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `taggable_taggables` (`created_at`, `tag_id`, `taggable_id`, `taggable_type`, `updated_at`) values (2016-07-05 21:24:20, 1, , App\blog, 2016-07-05 21:24:20))

Here is my controller

```
 public function blogstore(Request $request){


     $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required|max:255|unique:blogs',
        'summary' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'image' => 'image',
        'agree' =>  'required',
    ]);

    $blog = new blog;
    $blog->title = $request->title;
    $blog->summary = $request->summary;
    $blog->content = $request->description;
    $blog->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $blog->slug = EasySlug::generateSlug($blog->title, $separator = '-');
    $blog->tag('Apple,Banana,Cherry');
    $blog->tag->taggable_id = 1;
    if($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $file = Input::file('image');
        //getting timestamp
        $timestamp = str_replace([' ', ':'], '-', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());

        $name = $timestamp. '-' .$file->getClientOriginalName();

        $blog->image = $name;

        $file->move(public_path().'/../public_html/img/blog/', $name);

        $thumb = Image::make(public_path().'/../public_html/img/blog/' . $name)->resize(1366,786)->save(public_path().'/../public_html/img/blog/thumb/' . $name, 90);
    }

    $blog->save();
    return redirect()->route('admin.blog.index')->with('status', 'Blog Posted Successfully');
}
```

Comment: i understand its going null but how to add my blog id here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note:

```
insert into `taggable_taggables`
    (`created_at`       , `tag_id`, `taggable_id`, `taggable_type`, `updated_at`) 
                                       |
values                                 |
    (2016-07-05 21:24:20, 1       ,    |         , App\blog       , 2016-07-05 21:24:20))
                                       ^     what's missing here?
```

Comment: How i put my Blog Id Here in This Package